# Access token for Service Account in postman contains lots of

Tags: postman, google-oauth, service-accounts

My access_token contains lot of ...

I need to manually copy only the relevant parts of the access token (without trailing ...) to follow up requests.

How do I parse this access token to variable in postman without trailing ..., because if I put

```
pm.environment.set("AccessToken", accessToken);
```

above line in **Tests** section in postman, then AccessToken variable

[image]

Comment: How did you get an access token from a service account using postman?  Would you mind posting the code as well as the image you have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I'm able to remove trailing ... from access token via following script in **Tests** part of request

```
var response = pm.response.json()
var accessToken = response.access_token;
while(accessToken.charAt(accessToken.length-1) == '.')
{
    accessToken = accessToken.substr(0, accessToken.length-1);
}
pm.collectionVariables.set("AccessToken", accessToken);
```

@DalmTo
Here is how I did it. (I've used the existing collection with minor changes to the script - Sorry I forgot where I got script from)

There are 2 Request in total  (only 1st time 2 request, after that you only need to perform 2nd request)

**Pre-requisite step**

create collection variable **privateKey** and set its value to your PRIVATE KEY from .json file that you got during Service Account key creation.

eg.

```
{-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----*****(Complete PRIVATE Key excluding \n from it)****-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
}
```

[image: PrivateKey Variable]

**Request 1 Script** (you only need to run this script once)

```
GET  http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/jsrsasign-latest-all-min.js
```

in this request put following script in **Tests** section to save jsrsasign-js as collection variable

```
pm.collectionVariables.set('jsrsasign-js', responseBody);
```

**Request 2 Script** (you run this request every time you need token)

```
POST  https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
```

**Body**
x-www-form-urlencoded

grand_type : urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer

assertion : {{jwt}}

[image: Body]

**Pre-request Script**

```
var navigator = {};
var window = {};

eval(pm.collectionVariables.get("jsrsasign-js"));

var scope = pm.collectionVariables.get('scope');
var iss = pm.collectionVariables.get('iss');
var privateKey = pm.collectionVariables.get('privateKey');

const header = {"alg" : "RS256", "typ" : "JWT"};

const claimSet =
{
  "iss":"service account email",
  "sub":"user's email that you requesting token for",
  "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events" ,
  "aud":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "exp":KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now + 1hour").toString(),
  "iat": KJUR.jws.IntDate.get("now").toString()
}

console.log(`header: ${ JSON.stringify(header)}`);
console.log(`claim set: ${ JSON.stringify(claimSet) }`);

var jwt =  KJUR.jws.JWS.sign(null, header, claimSet, privateKey);
console.log(jwt);

pm.collectionVariables.set('jwt', jwt);
```

In the above script, you can change the value of
**"sub" : "User's email address"** to impersonate that user and get token on their behalf. Also, change **"Scope" : " to appropriate scope"**

Now when you run the second Request You will get token in response

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.a0ARr*********",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

You can add this script in **Tests** section of 2nd Request to parse that token to the collection variable and use that variable for all subsequent requests for Google API

```
var response = pm.response.json()
var accessToken = response.access_token;
while(accessToken.charAt(accessToken.length-1) == '.')
{
    accessToken = accessToken.substr(0, accessToken.length-1);
}
pm.collectionVariables.set("AccessToken", accessToken);
```

**Subsequent requests**

```
GET  https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarID/events
```

**Authorization**

Type : Bearer Token

Token : {{AccessToken}}

**Clarification**

When I'm requesting as particular user's token with "sub": "user's email", Access token that I received does not have trailing .... in them.